# Synchronizing sine waves from solar panel and grid electricity

Tags: inverter, wave, sine

I am new to the field of solar panel. I would like to install and use the electricity produced by the solar panels (through inverter) directly on the appliance, e.g. a fridge. In case of cloudy sky, I want to be able to withdraw electricity from the grid. I know of the sine wave difference between AC coming from the inverter and the grid.  Do you know of any equipment to synchronize them and where to buy it?

In case of power surplus from the solar panels, I wish to direct it to charge batteries instead of passing it to the grid.  Does anyone know if there is such an equipment and where to buy it?

Comment: Typically a "grid tie inverter" is used to sell power back to the utility company when it is in excess, and balance that consumed from the utility at night or on cloudy days.  Battery systems are quite different; in theory a hybrid is possible, but unusual.  Anyway, this is a *usage* question not an electronic *design* question, and so off topic here.

Comment: There are literally dozens of introductory level videos addressing this on youtube. Take a look at this for starters https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uobUwjCLfok. If you use a battery based system as a dedicated supply for a fridge etc you don't need a grid tie inverter as you're not connect to the grid. Any system that actually connects to the grid is going to be more complicated and expensive and needs to be professionally sized, setup and installed by an appropriately qualified electrician.

Answer (score 2):

An inverter designed to connect to the grid (grid tie inverter as mention in a comment) will do the synchronising to the grid frequency as part of its operation, also it is designed to prevent conditions like “islanding” for safety.

Even if you correctly size and purchase the correct grid tie inverter, get it professionaly installed and commissioned - most countries require this.

I installed our gt inverter, but had it professionally commissioned as they know all the parameters acceptable for the electricity supply companies.